# Is it possible to bind wpf controls to the properties of a sealed class?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Say you have a random class, one here oversimplified

```
public class Person
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }
    private string _gender;
    public string Gender
    {
        get
        {
            return _gender;
        }
        set
        {
            _gender = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to automatically create a textboxes and bind them to the properties of that class? Is this even possible at runtime?

I'm assuming you're going to want to get the properties and then bind them somehow to new WPF elements.

```
var properties = from p in typeof(Person).GetProperties()
                 where p.CanRead && !p.CanWrite
                 select p;
foreach (var property in properties)
{
    Label _label = new Label();
    Binding _binding = new Binding();
    _binding.Source = property;
    _binding.Path = new PropertyPath(property.PropertyType.GetProperties()[0].Name);
    _binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(_label, Label.ContentProperty, _binding);
    stackpanel.Children.Add(_label);
}
```

This obviously doesn't work, but I'm not entirely sure how to bind this properly.

Comment: Many things wrong here. 1: The class in your example is not sealed. 2: You are talking about TextBox, but are using Labels, why? 3: `!p.CanWrite` is wrong, the properties are not read-only. 4: The Binding's Source must not be the PropertyInfo, but an instance of `Person`. 5: The Binding's Path must be `property.Name`. 6: Setting UpdateSourceTrigger is pointless, because it only affects TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings.

Comment: Be aware that you do not bind to the "*properties of a class*" (which would be static properties), but to the properties of an instance of that class. You need a Person instance. There will of course also be no change notifications, since Person does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, so the whole idea of data binding might be pointless here. You need to provide more detail about what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. This works for sealed classes as well:

```
var properties = typeof(Person).GetProperties();
var instance = new Person() { Name = "name...", Gender = "gender..." };
foreach (var property in properties)
{
    Label _label = new Label();
    Binding _binding = new Binding();
    _binding.Source = instance;
    _binding.Path = new PropertyPath(property.Name);
    BindingOperations.SetBinding(_label, Label.ContentProperty, _binding);
    stackpanel.Children.Add(_label);
}
```

Note that you can only bind to public properties and that you also need to have an instance of the actual object (`Person`) to bind to.